# Some idea about why Wiles's work doesn't solve Beal conjecture: a soft question

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, diophantine-equations

I know that Wiles provided a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, as you can see for example from Wikipedia. But I know it (the fact that Wiles solved the problem) from an informative point of view. On the other hand I know a related/similar  problem to Fermat's Last Theorem, that is the so-called Beal conjecture, this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture)

Then the situation (from this my point of view, from the ignorance) is that a very elaborated and complicated theory (if I'm right about modular forms and elliptic curves) provide us a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem but it doesn't provide us a proof of the Beal conjecture.

> **Question.** Can you provide me an explanation (the detail*) about why the theory developed in Wiles's work doesn't solve Beal conjecture? **Many thanks.**

*I'm asking it as a soft question, and of course I understand that Fermat's Last Theorem and Beal conjecture are different problems, thus I am asking to get some idea/feedback (the mentioned *detail*) about why Wiles's work doesn't solve Beal conjecture, if such explanation is feasible in easy words.

Comment: Beal's conjecture is much stronger than Fermat's last theorem (that is implied by Beal's conjecture). I do not know the details, but as far as I understood Wiles used somehow properties of elliptic curves, which apparently does not cover the case of arbitary exponents.

Comment: @Peter Many thanks for your help. I hope that some user can provide me an explanation in words (an idea about it,  
even sacrificing a rigorous explanation with formulas) answering my question from an informative point of view. Feel free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Wiles did it was by proving the [Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem) for semistable elliptic curves. This meant that all elliptic curves (that mattered for this number-theoretic question) were secretly modular (or, more technically, had a modular parametrisation through a Galois representation).

Why was this important? Because of the [Frey Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frey_curve) - this essentially was an elliptic curve that, assuming there was a counter-example to FLT, would exist and would seemingly be *not* modular. This was proven as [Ribet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribet%27s_theorem) which stated further that if there were no non-modular elliptic curves of a specific kind (the semi-stable variety), then there would be no counterexamples to FLT (i.e. FLT was true).

So, while I don't know enough about the subject to know "why" creating an analagous curve to Frey's that had more general counterexamples to things referenced in Beal's Conjecture didn't happen/was impossible, I know the reason why Wiles' Proof was not related was because he simply was "stopping Frey's Curve from existing", which spoke *only* on FLT.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am going also take a look at the links.

Answer (score 2):

From a little reading up on it, I would say there are two key reasons:

1. Fermat's Last Theorem is a *special case* of Beal's conjecture. Beal's asks about $a^x+b^y=c^z$, while FLT only concerns $a^x+b^x=c^x$
2. (and the more likely reason why Wiles' work doesnt cover  Beal). FLT states there are $no$ solutions to $a^x+b^x=c^x$, however, Beal's regards that there $are$ solutions to $a^x+b^y=c^z$, and wants to know what qualities those solutions have. This disparity is most likely why Wiles' work on Fermat's couldn't bridge the gap.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: The second argument does not convince me. Beal's conjecture basically states that no solution with coprime integers exist. So, the fact that solutions exist plays no role because Beal's conjecture anyway assumes that $a,b,c$ are coprime. But I agree with the first argument.